# Best case time complexity for selection sort

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, selection-sort

Why is the best case time complexity for selection sort O(n^2) when it is O(n) for insertion sort and bubble sort? Their average times are same. I don't understand why the best case times are different. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insertion Sort vs. Selection Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799034/insertion-sort-vs-selection-sort)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For selection sort you have to search the minimum and put it on the first place in the first iteration. In the second iteration you have to search the minimum in the non-sorted part of the array and put it to the second place and so on...

You only know which element is the minimum after iterate till the end of the non-sorted part. Even if the array is sorted(!) you have to iterate till the end. Then you know for sure you found the minimum to put it on the right place (at the end of the already sorted part)

So first iteration takes n steps to find the minimum.
The second iteration takes n-1 steps to find the minimum in the non-sorted part
...
The last iteration takes 1 step to find the minimum in the non-sorted part.

After these steps you have an sorted array (even it was sorted before). Selection sort does not check if the array is already sorted by an linear-time algorithm. Selection sort repeatedly searches the minimum. That's the way how selection sort works.

When you repeatedly search the minimum it takes n+(n-1)+...+1 so you get (n(n+1))/2 = (n²+n)/2 which is in O(n²)

Comment: But isn't it the same case for bubble sort and insertion sort. We will do n iterations even if the array is sorted right? Why is their best case time O(n)?

Comment: As you mentioned bubble sort and insertion sort will do n iterations if the array is sorted. That's less than n^2 steps for selection sort because we need n iterations for each of the elements.

Comment: Ok got it.
In insertion sort, in each iteration if we find that the first element we are comparing is smaller than the key, we don't compare any further. So for a sorted array, the time is O(n)

Comment: @gartenkralle
But as we optimize bubble sort to bring the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n) by using one flag(for best case), can't we do the same for Selection Sort(for best case)?

Comment: @ANUPAM The difference is in the way the two algorithms check the elements.  In bubble sort, you compare every element to its neighbor on a pass so in a single pass if no swaps occur you can say that the array is sorted.  With selection sort, you are only comparing the current index to the unsorted side so you can not derive from a single pass that the unsorted side is sorted and are forced to continue.

Comment: @RyanMcArthur
@gartenkralle
work around is commented as //extra
Please let me know how you see this solution.

`selectionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
 int i, j, min_idx;
 for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
 {
  min_idx = i;
  int sorted_flag=0; //extra
  for (j = i+1; j < n; j++){
      if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
       min_idx = j;
      if(arr[j] > arr[j-1]){ //extra
          sorted_flag++;
      }
  }
  if(sorted_flag==n-i-1){ //extra
      printf("\nThe array is sorted already\n");
      break;
  }
  if(min_idx != i)
   swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);
 }
}`

Comment: @RyanMcArthur 

please refer the code in ide
https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/8b2e389e-4e30-4273-abb6-4c8d87e7c327