# Time Complexity of Selection sort

Tags: time-complexity, selection-sort

```
start = 0
while (start!= len(array)-1):
    for i in range(start +1,len(array)):
            if (array[i]<array[start]):
                    array[i],array[start] = array[start],array[i]
                    print(array)
    start += 1
```

in this case should'nt the complexity be like 
O(n) = n * [(n-1) + (n-2) + .... (n-(n-1))]
as for each of the n times of the outer loop the inner loop  runs for diff steps gradually reducing by one. In this way O(n) comes to be (n^3 - n^2)/2. What is wrong with my approach.?`enter code here`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best case time complexity for selection sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298396/best-case-time-complexity-for-selection-sort)

Answer (score 0):

Look at that in this way. The first time (start=0) the inner loop performs n-1 steps,
the second time (start=1) the inner loop performs n-2 steps, and so on. Thus you have:

(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 steps, which is equals to (n^2-n)/2 steps.